# superfluous output of yield_content

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I see strange output in my pages when I use `yield_content`. Please see below.
Notice the `[#<Proc:0x850a14c@/home/akonsu/project/index.erb:1>]` part. What is this?

layout.erb:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield_content :head %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>`

index.erb:

`<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<% end %>
<div id="contents">
...
</div>`

output:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
[#<Proc:0x850a14c@/home/akonsu/project/index.erb:1>]
  </head>
  <body>`

<div id="contents">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because of `<%=`. In ruby 1.9 it should use `<%` instead.

`<% yield_content :head %>`